Помогите сделать рамки прозрачными, чтобы был просто текст на фоне
Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать фон прозрачным в атрибуте .Label, .Radiobutton?
Нужно чтобы была только текстовая надпись, без рамок.
Код:
root.image = tk.PhotoImage(file='new-photo.png')
bg = tk.Label(root, image=root.image)
bg.place(x=0, y=0)

root.resizable(False,False)

lbl1 = tk.Label(root, text='тест',font='bold').pack(ipadx=0, ipady=15)

stavka = tk.IntVar()
tk.Radiobutton(root, text='тест', variable=stavka, value=1).pack()

Видел есть специальный метод Canvas, но разобраться не могу как верно его использовать.


Чтобы текст без фона был - используйте метод create_text холста. radiobutton - никак не сделать, разве что вручную круг рисовать.

Спасибо. Это через метод Canvas. Но все равно, он фон делает белым, а мне нужно чтобы текст был на моем фоне основном, который я загрузил как bg.
Как это можно сделать?

Canvas - это не метод, это класс. Чтобы без фона было, нужно Label вообще заменить на canvas.create_text, ну и radiobutton как-то тоже вручную отрисовывать через create_oval и create_text (т.е. вручную рисовать круг и текст). Если просто размещать Label и Radiobutton - они все равно с своим фоном будут, это никак не исправить.

Спасибо, понял)
